# why meteor app is not runing in my ubuntu OS

Tags: node.js, meteor

i have installed meteor js but when i going to run any app using command meteor it gives me an error like this.

```
'/home/user2/.meteor' exists, but '/home/user2/.meteor/meteor' is not executable. Remove it and try again.
```

snapshot [image]

Comment: You have installed Meteor using the root user. Any particular reason for doing it? Uninstall Meteor completely and reinstall using your own user.

Comment: sudo rm -rf /home/user2/.meteor and then reinstall